# anti-forgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken, machinekey

Some forms in my asp.net website cause "anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" exception. I tried some of the solutions but they did not work:

- I dont't have duplicate `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in my form.
- I dont't use web farm but I tried adding `machineKey`. I used `AutoGenerate` but it has no effect.
- I added fixed machine key value with `IsolateApps` but it complains "Decryption key specified has invalid hex characters".
- I removed `IsolateApps` and application pool stopped.

What else I can do? Why this happens?
Thanks.

Comment: What charset are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a duplicate `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in a partial view?

Comment: Yes. And It used to work but with no reason it stopped to do.

Comment: Try removing the duplicates...if you use ajax, you can reference the token this way: `$('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();`